# Forcefully update to new windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1809

The Windows 10 October 2018 update (v1809) rollout got cancelled multiple times, however you can still get the ISO files of it. Is it somehow possible to update using the ISO files (without losing files) or to enforce an update over windows update?

I don't want to do a clean install because it would take me multiple days on the machine I want to upgrade, however I need to upgrade it because of some bugs fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to update using the ISO files (without losing files) or to enforce an update over windows update?

As of November 13, 2018, you can either use the Upgrade Assistant, Media Creation Tool, or Windows Update to upgrade to Windows 10 October 2018 Update (1809)(17763.107).

If you want to install it through Windows Update you would have to change your release channel to Semi-Annual Targeted.

> I don't want to do a clean install because it would take me multiple days on the machine I want to upgrade, however, I need to upgrade it because of some bugs fixed in the latest version.

Bugs fixed in 17763.107 that are applicable to 1803 and 1709 would have also been patched in their respective cumulative patches.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly recommended to wait for official release of version 1809,
since it has a problem that destroys your files on installation,
and without any warning or log of what it did.
Microsoft has therefore retired all downloads of the ISO, for a good reason.

You may still download the ISO from the
[TechBench site](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/public.php).

You may create a boot USB from the ISO by using the free tool
[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html)
and install this version from the USB disk.

I repeat that you may lose files from installing this version and never
know which ones. It's much better to wait for the official release.

Comment: Can I install it from usb without doing a clean install (like windows update does)?

Comment: Yes, if the installation detects the existing Windows installation, it will just "upgrade" it to itself, while (hopefully) also fixing your problem.

Comment: its still downloadable http://microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO

Comment: @StevenPenny: It now got re-released with fixes. This is maybe the official release I said to wait for. But I would counsel still to wait until it is distributed in Windows Update. Because of the bugs it's better to wait as long as possible.