# Update Windows 10 to 1809 manually

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I'm on a `Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)` update channel. It's been a while after Microsoft released an update to fix issues in the initial Windows 10 1809 update. But a [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information) where we can download the updates as standalone packages still has a hole instead of download link to the 1809.17763.1 version package:

[image]

Windows 10 Update Assistant [page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) is useless as well, since it offers to download April 2018 Update, lol.

So, I can't update my 1803.17134.376 to 1809 even after more than a month since it's initially was released.

(Of course, "drastically improved" Windows Update doesn't suggest the 1809 update, too. Actually, it has been never working on this Win 10 copy, so I used to download all the updates manually via the first link in this post.)

Has anybody figured out a way of how to manually update from 1803 to 1809?

Without hardcore stuff, please, like making bootable media which potentially would have a great chance of destroying the currently installed Win 10 copy.

(I was completely confused by that "Microsoft recommends" wording near the 1809 update on that page and some top articles in Google saying that it was released and ready for production with that quick patch. So, this question is from this confusion.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is Microsoft has NOT re-released 1809 yet. So long as you are sticking to the full release versions you do not yet have the option to install 1809.

There has been little in the way of news regarding when the OS will be ready, but I'm hoping and assuming Microsoft is putting this time to good use and identifying and fixing many bugs.

The only way to get builds later than 1803 at this time (2018/11/05) is to use the various Insider Preview options.

**UPDATE Effective 2018/11/13**

On November 13th 2018 Microsoft re-released 1809 and began a slow and targeted roll-out.

If you wish to install the update manually after this date follow the instructions at the linked question: [Forcefully update to new windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1370491/forcefully-update-to-new-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Finally, Microsoft officially [released Windows 10 1809 update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information):

[image]

So, now we can update to it the usual way, for instance, via Windows Update or manually downloading the update package from the page above.

Another way that've also started working now is [Windows Update Assistant Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

I'd like to mention that at the moment this update is pushed to `Semi-Annual Channel (Targeted)` only. I discourage you from changing your update channel, if you're currently on purpose on another one.