# What can defer a windows 10 update besides the update channel and the number of defer days?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v1803

I have my updates on Windows 10 Education set to the **Semi-Annual Channel** and the **defer time** for both feature updates as well as quality updates are **set to 0 days**.

Despite this I'm stuck at Version 1709 (Fall creators update) although according to [this document from Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/windows-10/release-information) Version 1803 is available since 10 July 2018 on the Semi-Annual Channel.

Furthermore I have noticed that Windows starts downloading Version 1803 if I stay on the Semi-Annual Channel and set the defer times to 1 day which makes no sense to me but at least shows that my system seems to have no general incompatibility with 1803.

Therefore I have two question:

- What could be a reason that I don't get update 1803? Is there anything besides the update channel and defer time that influences this?
- How can a higher number of update defer days lead to the installation of new updates?

---

Just to clarify: I'm not asking how I can install update 1803 (I know that I can either force it by manually installing from the ISO or I can set the number of defer days to 1 and install it that way). Instead I'm interested in what could have prevented the update when defer days was set to 0 and why it is offered when I increase the number of defer days.

Comment: "What could be a reason that I don't get update 1803?' - It's likely due to you using Education.  The way you could verify this is, download the current Windows 10 Education 1803 ISO, perform the upgrade to 1803, and then verify if you are offered 1809.

Comment: I don't think it is due to using Education because my brother uses an Education version as well and he got update 1803 and even 1809 since he is on "Semi-Annual (targeted)". I will not get 1809 currently anyway since it isn't released yet for the "Semi-Annual Channel" but only for "Semi-Annual Channel (targeted)".

Comment: Try my suggestion.  There might be hardware that is blocking 1803.  I also know if you have Developer mode on that blocks 1803+.  My suggestion will provide the reason 1803 is being blocked...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have developer mode activated, so this is very likely the reason. I will try what you suggested as soon as I have time tomorrow.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1407284/cannot-seem-to-get-build-1809-update-installed-on-windows-10/1408627#1408627

Comment: On second thought and after further research I'm quite sure that developer mode is not the issue. First, I have only found reports of problems (amongst others the one you linked) of developer mode related to the update from 1803 to 1809. As stated in the question, I don't even get update to 1803 if defer days are set to 0 and if I set defer days to 1 I get 1803 (or at least it starts downloading) despite developer mode being active. I will check if the update to 1803 is successful tomorrow, but I'm still curious why the update process does only start if I increase the defer date.

Comment: I am 100% positive, you will find, that Developer Mode actually is the issue.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but either I misunderstand what you what me to do or developer mode really isn't the problem in my case. Here is what I did: Set update defer days to 0 and disable dev mode, then check for updates -> no updates found. Enable dev mode again and check for updates again just to be sure -> obviously still no update. With dev mode enabled set defer days to 1, check for updates -> 1803 was immediately found, downloaded and installed successfully. So 1803 is installed now and 1809 is offered when I switch to the targeted channel (despite active dev mode).